# Overloading constructor in annotation

Tags: kotlin, constructor, annotations

Is it possible to overloaded constructor of annotation

I'd like to have something to this:

```
enum class Notes(val name: String, val comment: String)
{
    A("A", "comment for A"),
    B("B", "comment for B")
}

@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS)
annotation class Note (val name: String, val comment: String) {
  constructor (note: Notes) : this(note.name, this.comment)
}

@Note("Foo", "comment for Foo)
class Foo() {
}

@Note(Notes.B)
class Bar() {
}
```

Yeah, I know that members is not allowed in annotation class but maybe I skiped something in docs

Comment: You cannot. How about creating two annotations with different names?

Comment: Yeah, I thought about two annotations  but it's not such elegant)
Thanks for the answer